# on mouse leave clear and start over conditions

Tags: jquery, loops, mousemove

i created a maze and i want to set an event(or what it takes) that when user mouse leave 
(after he failed) it will clear the colored way for he can start over again

```
  $(".way").bind('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#highlight_lose').fadeIn(400);
})
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/8/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$(".wall").css("background",'#fff');` to `#highlight_lose` and `#finish`

```
$('#highlight_lose').bind('mouseleave', function() {
$(this).fadeOut(400);  
$(".wall").css("background",'#fff'); 
})

$('#finish').bind('mouseenter', function() {
$('#highlight_win').fadeIn(400); 
$(".wall").css("background",'#fff'); 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/22/